# Why is Kotlin's mutableListOf() returning a null value

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working through Google's Android developer codelab for the the unscramble app. I am trying to initialize my variable `wordsList` to be an empty mutable list of strings with:

`private var wordsList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()`

However, during my debugging process, I see that the value of `wordsList` is `null` and not an empty list like `[]`. I tested the code in kotlin playground and it should be `[]`. I attached a screenshot of what android studio is showing me. What am I doing wrong, why am I not seeing the expected behavior?
[image]

Here is the gradle file for my project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the gradle file for my app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.unscramble"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    // LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    // ViewModel
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
}
```

Comment: When did you put the breakpoint? You might have put the breakpoint before it was initialized.

Comment: @marstran i have updated the screenshot. The breakpoint is after the variable should be initialized. Oh my god. I think I see the issue.

Comment: @marstran so i guess this leads to my next question: should those vars be defined in the `init` block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors):

> During an instance initialization, the initializer blocks are executed
> in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with
> the property initializers

So, your breakpoint is probably hit from the upper `init { }` block when `wordsList` is not initialized yet. You may choose to initialize your variable before calling `getNextWord()` or just move this `init { }` block down so it is executed when all your properties are already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problem.
Putting the init block after the variable declaration solved the problem for me

```
private var wordsList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
...
init {
    Log.d("GameFragment", "GameViewModel created!")
    getNextWord()
}
```